# The modulo two sum sign in LaTeX

Tags: math-mode, symbols, math-operators

I would like to know how I can obtain the 'modulo two sum' sign (unicode 2A0A i.e., the letter sigma with a circle in its middle).

[image]

I know I can obtain it by using the unicode-math package. But does anybody know an alternative method to obtain it? For information, I use TexMaker. Thanks for answering me. Best regards.

Comment: Try this first. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-symbol

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's an alternative that uses TikZ. With the `amsmath` and `tikz` packages loaded, put the following in your preamble

```
\newcommand\constructosum[3]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(char.base), inner sep=0, outer sep=0]
        \draw (#1,0) circle (#2); 
        \node (char) at (0,0) {$#3\sum$}; % Want to define a second symbol for inline...
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\newcommand{\modtwosum}{\mathop{\mathchoice
        {\constructosum{-0.3ex}{0.1}{\displaystyle}}
        {\constructosum{-0.3ex}{0.06}{\textstyle}}
        {\constructosum{-0.2ex}{0.04}{\scriptstyle}}
        {\constructosum{-0.15ex}{0.03}{\scriptscriptstyle}}
    }\displaylimits
}
```

This defines four operators corresponding to display style math environments, inline math, script size math and script script size math in that order. Each has a coordinate for the loop which may be adjusted, and a size for the loop. For example the display style version has

```
\constructosum{-0.3ex}{0.1}{\displaystyle}
```

which places the loop at `-0.3ex` (moves it horizontally backwards a bit) with a radius of 0.1cm. To use it, simply use the new operator `\modtwosum` inside any math environment. e.g.

```
\[
G=\modtwosum_a^b H
\]
```

A demo of this operator in each of the four situations that may occur:

[image]

Thanks goes to egreg for [pointing out](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/46389/9043) that I could reduce the original version of this with a helper `\newcommand` to contain the TikZ code.

Comment: That's OK. When using the displaymath mode (and not the math mode), the letters and the circle appear at their right places in the 2nd solution. For the first, even in displaymath, the circle is slightly moved to the right with regard to its expected position. Thanks a lot.

Comment: What you mean? `displaymath` is math mode. You'll have to define a second symbol for inline math though, but this will be just a variation on the above.

Comment: displamath : \begin{displaymath} ... \end{displaymath} and math : $ ... $

Comment: My code will work in all equation environments except `$...$` style inlines. These include the usual `\[...\]`, `equation`, `align` etc.

Comment: Please note that `$...$` is usually referred to as inline math, *not* simply math. Display style math is naturally assumed unless otherwise stated. Secondly, it is *normal* for the `a` and `b` to appear to the right of the sum symbol in inline math, in order to save vertical space (try `$G=\sum_a^b$` and you see the same behaviour).

Comment: I've copied that! Thanks a lot for your expertise and your help. Same thing to you diabonas.

Comment: @Robert: I've reduced it down to a final version that makes it easier to tweak.

Comment: @Robert: No problem. Just remember to upvote the answers that helped and to accept an answer when you've settled on a one that works for you. :)

Comment: @MarkS.Everitt I wouldn't use `\DeclareMathOperator*`, but `\mathop` and `\displaylimits`. The macro is intended for defining "text" operators, rather than symbols, and does many things which are useless here.

Comment: You're right. Is `displaylimits` needed though? I just modified my code and it doesn't seem necessary.

Comment: @MarkS.Everitt It's actually the default, but it's clearer to add it, IMO, so that it's evident what the wanted action is.

Comment: @egreg: A very good point!

Answer (score 5):

The [`fdsymbol`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/fdsymbol) package provides this symbol as `\osum` or `\modtwosum`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fdsymbol}
\begin{document}
$\modtwosum$
\end{document}
```

#### Result:

[image: the \modtwosum symbol as provided by fdsymbol]

However, this changes the math font of your whole document. If that's not what you want, you can just import this single symbol without loading `fdsymbol`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareFontFamily{U}{FdSymbolE}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{FdSymbolE}{m}{n}{
    <-7.1> s * [1.0] FdSymbolE-Book
    <7.1-> s * [1.0] FdSymbolE-Book
}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{FdSymbolE}{b}{n}{
    <-7.1> s * [1.0] FdSymbolE-Medium
    <7.1-> s * [1.0] FdSymbolE-Medium
}{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{fdlargesymbols}{U}{FdSymbolE}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{fdlargesymbols}{bold}{U}{FdSymbolE}{b}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\tosum}{\mathop}{fdlargesymbols}{"3A}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\dosum}{\mathop}{fdlargesymbols}{"3B}
\makeatletter
\def\modtwosum{\DOTSB\tosum\slimits@}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
$\modtwosum$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Doesn't this package completely change the mathematics typeface though?

Comment: A compilation error appears at line 1548 in the release I use: "\vec is already defined"...

Comment: @MarkS.Everitt You're right, it does replace the whole math alphabet. See my updated answer on how to import only this very symbol, without affecting the rest.

Comment: @Robert Most likely one the packages you use is not compatible with `fdsymbol` (e. g. `amssymb`). In this case, try my updated solution which doesn't rely on loading `fdsymbol` to avoid such conflicts.

Answer (score 1):

If you find no other alternative, then perhaps this will work. You'll need to use the `mathtools` package. Use the following declaration in your preamble:

```
\DeclareMathOperator*{\osum}{\mathrlap{\hspace{1ex}\circ}{\sum}}
```

Now you can use the new `\osum` operator, and it'll behave like the usual `\sum` operator with respect to subscripts and superscripts.

```
G=\osum_a^b H
```

[image]

Comment: `mathtools` loads `amsmath`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But when using this code the letters a, b and the circle appears on the right side of sigma. I'm investigating...