# Writing specific versions of an operator for display and inline modes

Tags: tikz-pgf, amsmath, math-operators, inline, displaystyle

I'm busy answering a question by constructing a new math operator that uses the sum symbol and some TikZ placed on top. My answer as it stands can be found [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/46360/9043). It looks (I think) pretty good in display style, but too large when shown inline. Even if it automatically set the sum symbol into inline size, the placement of the TikZ would be off.

Is there a way to define different code for when the operator is used in display mathematics environments, and when it's inline? Alternatively, is there a way to detect when you are in display or inline mode?

From the aforementioned example, here is the code I constructed:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}

% Modify the coordinate (-0.3ex,0) to adjust alignment, and (0.1) to adjust the size.
\DeclareMathOperator*{\osum}{\ensuremath{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(char.base), inner sep=0, outer sep=0]
        \draw (-0.3ex,0) circle (0.1); 
        \node (char) at (0,0) {$\displaystyle\sum$};  % Want to define a second symbol for inline...
    \end{tikzpicture}}%
}

\begin{document}

\[
G=\osum_a^b H
\]

And now in inline mode the equation $G=\osum_a^b H$ is obviously too big.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

TeX features a special primitive for this very case. However, you will have to specify code for all *four* math styles:

```
\mathchoice{display}{text}{script}{scriptscript}
```

See [TeX by Topic](http://ctan.org/pkg/texbytopic) for more information.

Comment: Wonderful! This worked like a dream. See [the updated answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/46360/9043) for the result.

Answer (score 13):

Taking the definitions you make in the other question, here's a way: `\mathchoice` has four arguments, stating what's to be done in the various situations; `\mathop` states how the symbol should be considered with respect to spacing and ending with `\displaylimits` ensures the same behavior as `\sum`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\osum}{ 
  \mathop{
    \mathchoice
      {\buildosum{\displaystyle}{0.1}}
      {\buildosum{\textstyle}{0.075}}
      {\buildosum{\scriptstyle}{0.075}}
      {\buildosum{\scriptscriptstyle}{0.075}}
  }\displaylimits 
}

\newcommand\buildosum[2]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(char.base), inner sep=0, outer sep=0]
    \draw (-0.3ex,0) circle (#2);
    \node (char) at (0,0) {$#1\sum$};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}

\[\osum_a^b x\]

$\osum_a^b x$

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you need more parameters to adjust the circle's position in smaller styles, modify accordingly the definition. Using a two-step approach makes the code more easily maintainable.

Comment: I was just in the process of condensing it down like this. I'm a little confused about the placement of the `#1` though...

Comment: `\buildosum` has two parameters: the style to use and the circle diameter.

Comment: Ah, I see now. I didn't read the brackets properly.

Comment: I've added them for greater clarity; they are not strictly necessary as the first unbraced token will be the first argument anyway. When I'm writing low level code, I'm influenced by the old habits developed when I was using Plain TeX or AMSTeX. :)

Comment: I added a new version partly based on this in my answer. Thanks for the help. :)