# How do I put a circle around an operator?

Tags: math-operators, logic

For example, I want to put a circle around `\land`, just like one can put a circle around `+` by writing `\oplus`. Is there a general method to do this?

Comment: With `\usepackage{stmaryrd}` you can choose between `\owedge` and `\varowedge`. The former is lighter than the latter. Before building a symbol by hand, try and see if it's already available: see [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/9365).

Comment: See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7032/good-way-to-make-textcircled-numbers for a similar question with numbers instead of an operator.

Answer (score 24):

Here's a version combining `\land` and `\bigcirc`:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand\incircbin
{%
  \mathpalette\@incircbin
}
\newcommand\@incircbin[2]
{%
  \mathbin%
  {%
    \ooalign{\hidewidth$#1#2$\hidewidth\crcr$#1\bigcirc$}%
  }%
}
\newcommand{\oland}{\incircbin{\land}}
\makeatother
```

It will change size according to math style:

```
\[a\oland b\frac{a\oland b}{a\oland b^{a\oland b^{a\oland b}}}\]
```

gives

[image: oland example]

Comment: There are unnecessary braces inside the `\ooalign`. I'd use `\hidewidth` rather than `\hfil`, but it's not so important, in this case.

Comment: Your small symbols are not correct, circles seems to be ellipses !

Comment: @Altermundus Well that's what `\bigcirc` looks like at this style. Observe `\land` also changes proportion. I believe there is some bigger scheme behind this ;-)

Answer (score 17):

**Update**

More correct is the next code, I used the code from egreg [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46376/writing-specific-versions-of-an-operator-for-display-and-inline-modes)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\circleland}{ 
  \mathbin{
    \mathchoice
      {\buildcircleland{\displaystyle}}
      {\buildcircleland{\textstyle}}
      {\buildcircleland{\scriptstyle}}
      {\buildcircleland{\scriptscriptstyle}}
  } 
}

\newcommand\buildcircleland[1]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(X.base), inner sep=0, outer sep=0]
    \node[draw,circle] (X)  {$#1\land$};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}

\[a\circleland b\frac{a\circleland b}{a\circleland b^{a\circleland b^{a\circleland b}}}\]    

$x \circleland (y\circleland z)$ and  $x \land (y\land z)$     
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Apart from the abstract question "is this possible", is it really a good idea to make a math operator based on TikZ? As it's a basic logical operator, an average thesis or monograph in the field will contain several thousand instances of these. Add to that `\mathchoice` effects plus the fact that `amsmath` executes everything in an aligned environment twice, wouldn't this mean a lot of running time? Do you have experience with defining math operators with TikZ? Shouldn't this at least be solved with some caching in boxes?

Comment: Like egreg writes, the good way is to search inside "The Comprehensive LATEX Symbol List" http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/symbols/comprehensive/. Now for the running time, I don't know. It will be interesting to test. For the math operator with tikz, you can give a look at the  excellent answer  from egreg : http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46376/writing-specific-versions-of-an-operator-for-display-and-inline-modes.

Comment: egregs suggestion is applicable only if the symbol does indeed already exist. I'm interpreting the answers here as general advice on how to make a circled math operator. I just tested your symbol, and another issue is that it doesn't change size in `\scriptstyle` etc.

Comment: I just made a small test with about 5000 symbols in one doc, and my version runs about 40 times faster than yours ;-)

Comment: Yes I think it's possible and normal that your code is faster.

Comment: Great you made a version which changes size with math style! Though I think "more efficient" is not the right way to put it. Note that `\mathchoice` typesets **all four** of its arguments, so now your solution is 200 times slower than mine :-) Furthermore, maybe you should also adapt line width, as the stroke of `\land` becomes thinner at smaller styles. Lastly, `\mathop` might not be the best choice because it'll look strange in front of parentheses. Compare `x \circleland (y\circleland z)` with `x \land (y\land z)`. I suggest `\mathbin`.

Comment: Way to go! I hope I'm not pestering you with comments, but may I ask what the second argument to `\buildcircleland` is for? It doesn't seem to be used.

Comment: Yes you are right  `\mathbin` is a better option than `\mathop` and I corrected a bug with the limits. Yes you are also right with `\mathchoice` this macro is not very efficient !

Comment: @StephanLehmke Nothing I forgot to modify egreg's macro !

Comment: @StephanLehmke `mathpalette` is a wrapper to `mathchoice` `\def\mathpalette#1#2{\mathchoice ...`. It will be interesting, when you test the two methods to load in each code TikZ.

Comment: That's clear, as in fact `\mathchoice` is the only way to react to math styles in complex macros. `\mathpalette` is only more convenient when all I need is the math style switch. So our solutions are on equal odds now :-) I don't understand the TikZ bit of your comment. Do you mean the loading time of TikZ itself? Thats completely insignificant. A document with 5000 operators takes 0.2s for my solution and 45s for your solution here on my Linux box. Nearly nothing of this is spent on loading TikZ.

Answer (score 8):

You can use `pgf` for this purpose by defining a new command:

```
\newcommand{\circleland}{
\tikz{
\pgfsetbaselinepointlater{\pgfpointanchor{X}{base}}
\pgfcircle{\pgfpointorigin}{0.15cm}
\pgfusepath{stroke}
\node (X) {$\land$};
}}
```

Look at this MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\circleland}{
\tikz{
\pgfsetbaselinepointlater{\pgfpointanchor{X}{base}}
\pgfcircle{\pgfpointorigin}{0.15cm}
\pgfusepath{stroke}
\node (X) {$\land$};
}}
\begin{document}
\[x \land y\]

\begin{equation}
x \circleland y
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

the result will be:

[image]

Comment: I suggest using `inner sep/outer sep=0pt` and use the command `\mathop` to get the correct spacing.

Answer (score 6):

I am giving the general answer to the question (valid for any operator and even text) by slightly modifying [Alain's](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/3144/alain-matthes) code.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{tikz}

%The given symbol or text (\text{mytext}) in a circle
%To be used always in math mode
\newcommand{\circlesign}[1]{ 
    \mathbin{
        \mathchoice
        {\buildcirclesign{\displaystyle}{#1}}
        {\buildcirclesign{\textstyle}{#1}}
        {\buildcirclesign{\scriptstyle}{#1}}
        {\buildcirclesign{\scriptscriptstyle}{#1}}
    } 
}

\newcommand\buildcirclesign[2]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(X.base), inner sep=0, outer sep=0]
    \node[draw,circle] (X)  {\ensuremath{#1 #2}};
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}


\begin{document}

    $\circlesign{+} \neq \oplus$,  $\circlesign{\bullet} \neq \odot$ \\
    Put whatever you want inside the circle $\circlesign{\davidsstar}$

    $\circlesign{\text{whatever!}}$

\end{document}
```

Comment: +1.  But note that you can use the `\mathpalette` macro here, specifically designed for this kind of tasks.  More specifically, I’d say `\DeclareRobustCommand*{\circlesign}[1]{\mathbin{\mathpalette{\buildcirclesign}{#1}}}`.

Answer (score 2):

I spent some time trying to get the <,<=,=,>= and > operators circled nicely. Code ended up a bit *hacky*, even though it worked:

<

```
\Large \textcircled{\normalsize \$\hspace{0.05 mm} &lt;\$} \normalsize
```

<=

```
\Large \textcircled{\raisebox{1pt} {\normalsize \$\hspace{0.05 mm} \leq\$}} \normalsize
```

=

```
\Large \textcircled{\raisebox{1pt} {\normalsize \$\hspace{0.05 mm} =\$}} \normalsize
```

>=

```
\Large \textcircled{\raisebox{1pt} {\normalsize \$\hspace{0.1 mm} \geq\$}} \normalsize
```

>

```
\Large \textcircled{\normalsize \$\hspace{0.1 mm} &gt;\$} \normalsize
```

The horizontal spacings are quite finicky. It ended up looking like this (center column):

[image: Big O table]

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the great answers! However, Stephan's original code produced an error in my project ("Illegal parameter number in definition of \reserved@a"). I did not figure out what exactly the problem was. I solved it by adding some `\protect`s, which seems to be a bit more robust. Here is my version of the MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}

\newcommand{\incircbin}[1]{%
  \mathbin{%
    \mathchoice%
    {\protect\incircint{\displaystyle}{#1}}%
    {\protect\incircint{\textstyle}{#1}}%
    {\protect\incircint{\scriptstyle}{#1}}%
    {\protect\incircint{\scriptscriptstyle}{#1}}%
  }%
}
\newcommand{\incircint}[2]{%
  \ooalign{$#1\bigcirc$\crcr\hidewidth$#1#2$\hidewidth\crcr}%
}
\newcommand{\circleland}{\incircbin{\land}}

\begin{document}

\[a\circleland b\frac{a\circleland b}{a\circleland b^{a\circleland b^{a\circleland b}}}\]    

\end{document}
```

[image: Rendering of MWE]

Matthias

Answer (score 1):

For me the idea from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/129100/292801) was very useful:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand*\circled[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{\node[draw,circle,thick,blue,text=black] (char) {#1};}}
\begin{document}
\noindent
Text: \circled{=} \newline
Math: $\circled{\textbf{=}}$
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

The other approaches weren't working for me because I was working in an environment where I couldn't define new macros or import packages. So my solution was to simply overlay `\bigcirc` and the symbol that I want inside the circle, in this case a `<`, by using `\hspace` to shift the inner symbol until it is aligned.

```
$\bigcirc\hspace{-12pt}<$
```

The result looks reasonable:

[image]

This approach takes a lot of manually fiddling, however, to make different symbols properly centered.