# Creating a circled operator which expands into a lozenge

Tags: math-operators

I have a LaTeX document which has a binary operator called "composition". Normally, this is written as a circled letter, where the letter is passed as a parameter: `\comp{x}`. I can achieve good results for this using techniques similar to [How do I put a circle around an operator?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53698/how-do-i-put-a-circle-around-an-operator).

However, sometimes the content of the operator get big, e.g. some calculation that renders as a few letters long: `\comp{x + y + z}`. In this instance, I don't want a giant circle with a diameter large enough to contain the text. I'd like to have the operator extend into a lozenge, the length of which depends on the length of the content. So, if the content is just one letter, it's just a letter in a circle. If it's several letters, it expands the circle horizontally into capsule that contains the content.

I have complete control of the build environment and package choice. The document will be quite long (200+ pages), so build time is a concern. However, the machine is quite punchy, so "heavy" solutions are possibly OK. The operator is used in math mode, and occasionally as a super/subscript, but should never get really tiny.  How can I achieve this goal?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This answer takes care of TeX/LaTeX's math typesetting stuff. Starting point is the solution of JLDiaz, that is based on Andrew Swann's answer.

- `\comp` should be a binary operator (`\mathbin`).
- The contents of `\comp` is set as math.
- Math is automatically resized if used in subscripts, inside fractions, …
  The `tikz` solution switches to text mode and back to math. There we need to know,
  which style is active (`\displaystyle`, `\textstyle`, `\scriptstyle`, `\scriptscriptstyle`). LaTeX's `\mathpalette` helps in setting this style (It uses
  TeX's `\mathchoice`).
- Math can be surrounded by additional space, controlled by `\mathsurround`. 
  When we switch intermediately from text to math, these space must not be added.
  LaTeX's `\m@th` helps in this case, because it sets `\mathsurround` to `0pt`.
- I switched from `ex` to `mu` to get a better scaling behaviour and use a dimen
  register to set `tikz`'s parameters including `inner sep` and `line width`.
- In the script styles TeX does not set additional space around binary operators.
  But IMHO it looks a little odd, if the adjacent symbols are more close to the
  box than its contents. Therefore a half thin space is added in script styles.
  And a quarter thin space in display and text styles. `\nonscript` ignores the
  following math glue in script styles.
- Also `minimum width` and an invisible rule are added to improve the behaviour
  for tiny or empty contents.
- `\comp` has an optional argument that pass options to the node settings.

The file:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\usepackage{color}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*\comp[2][]{%
  \ensuremath{%
    \mathbin{%
      \mathpalette{\comp@aux{#1}}{#2}%
    }%
  }%
}
\newdimen\comp@unit
\newcommand*{\comp@aux}[3]{%
  #2%
  \mskip.5\thinmuskip\nonscript\mskip-.25\thinmuskip
  \begingroup
    \sbox0{%
      $%
        \m@th % \mathsurround=0pt
        #2% \displaystyle, \textstyle, ...
        \mkern9mu %
      $%
    }%
  \edef\x{\endgroup
    \comp@unit=\the\wd0 %
  }\x
  \tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{%
    \node[
      rectangle,
      draw,
      minimum height=2\comp@unit,
      minimum width=2\comp@unit,
      rounded corners=\comp@unit,
      inner sep=.33\comp@unit,
      line width=.05\comp@unit,
      #1%
    ] (char) {%
      $%
        \m@th % \mathsurround=0pt
        #2% \displaystyle, \textstyle, ...
        \rule{0pt}{\comp@unit}%
        #3%
      $%
    };%
  }%
  \mskip.5\thinmuskip\nonscript\mskip-.25\thinmuskip
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$a \oplus b \ominus c$

$a \comp{x} b \comp{y} c \comp{} d \comp{Z} e \comp{\cdot} f$

$a \comp{x+y+z} b \comp{\displaystyle\int_0^\infty \frac{x}{z}\,\mathrm{d}x} c$

$a \comp{x} b^{c \comp{y} d}
\frac{e \comp{z} f}{g \comp{2x} h_{i \comp{2y} j}}$

$a \comp[red]{r} b \comp[green]{g} c \comp[blue]{b} d$

\end{document}
```

> [image: \comp examples]

Comment: All the answers are wonderful, but I think this pips it for completeness. The only mild annoyance is that the baselines are not lining up identically on otherwise "similarly" sized items (viz. r g b on the bottom line). Thanks muchly!

Comment: In the last line of the example the base lines for all letters `arbgcbd` are the same exactly. Of course, the circles can be centered at the math axis; just add `\vcenter{\hbox{$` in the first line of the definition of `\comp@aux` and `$}}` in the last line.

Answer (score 10):

Using `tikz` as in Andrew Swann's answer, but using a rectangle with rounded corners, instead of an ellipse, and carefully setting the corner radius and the rectangle height, you can get a nice approximation:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\usetikzlibrary{shapes}

\newcommand*\compel[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{
\node[rectangle,draw,minimum height=3ex, minimum width=3ex, rounded corners=1.5ex] (char) {#1};}}

\compel{x} \compel{\( x+y+z \)}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Have been trying to get a more general solution than the hard coded `3ex` with `\settowidth` and `\settoheight` (then taking the minimum) but the height doesn't seem to be calculated correctly, even with `\ensuremath`...

Answer (score 9):

Adapting the answers to [Good way to make \textcircled numbers?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7032/15925) one could use an `ellipse` shape from `tikz`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}

\newcommand*\compel[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{
\node[ellipse,draw,inner sep=0.5pt] (char) {#1};}}

\begin{document}
\compel{x} \compel{\( x+y+z \)}

\end{document}
```

[image: Ellipse sample]

The `cylinder` shape is annoyingly close to your wish

```
\newcommand*\compcy[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{
\node[cylinder,draw,inner sep=0.5pt] (char) {#1}; }}

\compcy{x} \compcy{\( x+y+z \)}
```

[image: Cylinder sample]

so one can go mad and try to adapt that code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}

\makeatletter
% Keys for shape flatcircle
%
% /pgf/shape aspect              : Ratio between the x and y radii of the flatcircle end.
% /pgf/flatcircle uses custom fill : Use a custom fill for the flatcircle.
% /pgf/flatcircle end fill         : Custom color for the flatcircle end.
% /pgf/flatcircle body fill        : Custom color for the flatcirclebody.
%

\newif\ifpgfflatcircleusescustomfill
\pgfkeys{/pgf/.cd,
    flatcircle uses custom fill/.is if=pgfflatcircleusescustomfill,
    flatcircle end fill/.initial=white,
    flatcircle body fill/.initial=white
}


\pgfdeclareshape{flatcircle}{%
    \savedmacro\getflatcirclepoints{%
        \pgfmathsetlength\pgf@xc{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/inner xsep}}%
        \pgf@x\pgf@xc%
        \advance\pgf@x.5\wd\pgfnodeparttextbox%
        \pgfmathsetlength\pgf@yc{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/inner ysep}}%
        \pgf@y\pgf@yc%
        \advance\pgf@y.5\ht\pgfnodeparttextbox%
        \advance\pgf@y.5\dp\pgfnodeparttextbox%
        \ifpgfshapeborderusesincircle%
            \pgfmathsetmacro\rotate{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/shape border rotate}}%
            \ifdim\pgf@x<\pgf@y%
                \pgf@x\pgf@y%
            \else%
                \pgf@y\pgf@x%
            \fi%
            \pgf@x1.414213\pgf@x%
            \pgf@y1.414213\pgf@y%           
        \else%
            \pgfmathmod{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/shape border rotate}}{360}%
            \ifdim\pgfmathresult pt<0pt\relax%
                \pgfmathadd@{\pgfmathresult}{360}%
            \fi%
            \pgfmathsetcount\c@pgf@counta{+\pgfmathresult}%
            \advance\c@pgf@counta45\relax%
            \divide\c@pgf@counta90\relax%
            \multiply\c@pgf@counta90\relax%
            \edef\rotate{\the\c@pgf@counta}%
            \ifnum\c@pgf@counta=90\relax%
                \pgf@xa\pgf@x%
                \pgf@x\pgf@y%
                \pgf@y\pgf@xa%
                \pgf@yc\pgf@xc%
            \else%
                \ifnum\c@pgf@counta=270\relax%
                    \pgf@xa\pgf@x%
                    \pgf@x\pgf@y%
                    \pgf@y\pgf@xa%
                    \pgf@yc\pgf@xc%
                \fi%
            \fi%
        \fi%
        \addtosavedmacro\rotate%
        \pgf@xa\pgf@x%
        \pgf@ya\pgf@y%
        \pgfutil@tempdima\pgfshapeaspect\pgf@ya%
        \pgfutil@tempdimb\pgf@ya%
        %
        % Adjust for minimum height.
        %
        \pgfmathsetlength\pgf@xc{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/minimum width}}%
        \ifdim\pgfutil@tempdimb<.5\pgf@xc\relax%
            \pgfutil@tempdimb.5\pgf@xc%
            \pgf@ya\pgfutil@tempdimb%
        \fi%
        %
        % Calculate how far the node contents can extend into the flatcircle bottom.
        %
        \pgf@yb\pgfutil@tempdimb%
        \advance\pgf@yb-\pgf@yc%
        \pgfmathdivide@{\pgfmath@tonumber{\pgf@yb}}{\pgfmath@tonumber{\pgfutil@tempdimb}}%
        \pgfmathasin@{\pgfmathresult}%
        \pgfmathcos@{\pgfmathresult}%
        \let\angle\pgfmathresult%
        \pgf@xb\pgfmathresult\pgfutil@tempdima%
        %
        % Adjust for minimum width.
        %
        \pgf@x.5\pgflinewidth%
        \advance\pgf@x2.0\pgf@xa%
        \advance\pgf@x3.0\pgfutil@tempdima%
        \advance\pgf@x-\pgf@xb%
        \pgfmathsetlength\pgf@xc{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/minimum height}}%
        \ifdim\pgf@x<\pgf@xc%
            \advance\pgf@xc-\pgf@x%
            \advance\pgf@xa.5\pgf@xc%
        \fi%        
        %
        % Add the larger of the outer sep to the radii.
        %
        \pgf@x\pgfutil@tempdima\relax%
        \pgf@y\pgfutil@tempdimb\relax%
        \pgfmathsetlength\pgf@xc{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/outer xsep}}%
        \pgfmathsetlength\pgf@yc{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/outer ysep}}%
        \ifdim\pgf@xc>\pgf@yc%
            \advance\pgf@x\pgf@xc%
            \advance\pgf@y\pgf@xc%
            \edef\outersep{\the\pgf@xc}%
        \else%
            \advance\pgf@x\pgf@yc%
            \advance\pgf@y\pgf@yc%
            \edef\outersep{\the\pgf@yc}%
        \fi%
        \edef\xradius{\the\pgf@x}%
        \edef\yradius{\the\pgf@y}%
        \addtosavedmacro\xradius%
        \addtosavedmacro\yradius%
        \addtosavedmacro\outersep%
        %
        \pgfextract@process\flatcirclecenter{%
            \pgf@x\pgfutil@tempdima%
            \advance\pgf@x.5\pgflinewidth%
            \advance\pgf@x\pgf@xb%
            \pgf@x.5\pgf@x% 
            \pgf@y0pt%
        }%
        \addtosavedmacro\flatcirclecenter%
        %
        \pgfextract@process\beforetop{%
            \pgf@x\pgf@xa%
                        \advance\pgf@x-\pgf@xb%
%           \advance\pgf@x\pgfutil@tempdima%
%           \advance\pgf@x.5\pgflinewidth%
            \pgf@y\pgf@ya%
        }%
        \pgfextract@process\afterbottom{%
            \pgf@x-\pgf@xa%
            \advance\pgf@x\pgf@xb%
            \pgf@y\pgf@ya%
        }%
        \addtosavedmacro\beforetop%
        \addtosavedmacro\afterbottom%       
        \pgfmathsetlength\pgf@yc{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/outer ysep}}%
        \pgfextract@process\beforetopanchor{%
            \beforetop%
            \advance\pgf@y\pgf@yc%
        }%
        \pgfextract@process\afterbottomanchor{%
            \afterbottom%
            \advance\pgf@y\pgf@yc%
        }%
        \addtosavedmacro\beforetopanchor%       
        \addtosavedmacro\afterbottomanchor% 
        %
        \beforetopanchor%
        \advance\pgf@x\xradius\relax%
        \ifdim\pgf@x>\pgf@y%
            \edef\externalradius{\the\pgf@x}%
        \else%
            \edef\externalradius{\the\pgf@y}%
        \fi%
        \addtosavedmacro\externalradius%
    }
    \savedanchor\centerpoint{%
        \pgf@x.5\wd\pgfnodeparttextbox%
        \pgf@y.5\ht\pgfnodeparttextbox%
        \advance\pgf@y-.5\dp\pgfnodeparttextbox%
    }%
    \savedanchor\midpoint{%
        \pgf@x.5\wd\pgfnodeparttextbox%
        \pgfmathsetlength\pgf@y{+0.5ex}%
    }%
    \savedanchor\basepoint{%
        \pgf@x.5\wd\pgfnodeparttextbox%
        \pgf@y0pt%
    }%
    \anchor{center}{\centerpoint}
    \anchor{shape center}{%
        \getflatcirclepoints%
        \pgfmathrotatepointaround{\pgfpointadd{\flatcirclecenter}{\centerpoint}}%
            {\centerpoint}{\rotate}%    
    }%
    \anchor{mid}{\midpoint}%
    \anchor{mid east}{%
        \getflatcirclepoints%
        \let\pgf@flatcircle@referencepoint\midpoint%
        \pgf@anchor@flatcircle@border{\pgfqpoint{\externalradius}{0pt}}%
    }%
    \anchor{mid west}{%
        \getflatcirclepoints%
        \let\pgf@flatcircle@referencepoint\midpoint%
        \pgf@anchor@flatcircle@border{\pgfqpoint{-\externalradius}{0pt}}%
    }%
    \anchor{base}{\basepoint}%
    \anchor{base east}{%
        \getflatcirclepoints%
        \let\pgf@flatcircle@referencepoint\basepoint%
        \pgf@anchor@flatcircle@border{\pgfqpoint{\externalradius}{0pt}}%
    }%
    \anchor{base west}{%
        \getflatcirclepoints%
        \let\pgf@flatcircle@referencepoint\basepoint%
        \pgf@anchor@flatcircle@border{\pgfqpoint{-\externalradius}{0pt}}%
    }%
    \anchor{north}{%
        \getflatcirclepoints%
        \pgf@anchor@flatcircle@border{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{\externalradius}}%
    }%
    \anchor{south}{%
        \getflatcirclepoints%
        \pgf@anchor@flatcircle@border{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{-\externalradius}}%
    }%
    \anchor{east}{%
        \getflatcirclepoints%
        \pgf@anchor@flatcircle@border{\pgfqpoint{\externalradius}{0pt}}%
    }%
    \anchor{west}{%
        \getflatcirclepoints%
        \pgf@anchor@flatcircle@border{\pgfqpoint{-\externalradius}{0pt}}%
    }%
    \anchor{north east}{%
        \getflatcirclepoints%
        \pgf@anchor@flatcircle@border{\pgfqpoint{\externalradius}{\externalradius}}%
    }%
    \anchor{south west}{%
        \getflatcirclepoints%
        \pgf@anchor@flatcircle@border{\pgfqpoint{-\externalradius}{-\externalradius}}%
    }%
    \anchor{south east}{%
        \getflatcirclepoints%
        \pgf@anchor@flatcircle@border{\pgfqpoint{\externalradius}{-\externalradius}}%
    }%
    \anchor{north west}{%
        \getflatcirclepoints%
        \pgf@anchor@flatcircle@border{\pgfqpoint{-\externalradius}{\externalradius}}%
    }%
    \anchor{before top}{%
        \getflatcirclepoints%
        \pgfmathrotatepointaround{\pgfpointadd{\beforetopanchor}{\centerpoint}}{\centerpoint}{\rotate}%
    }
    \anchor{top}{%
        \getflatcirclepoints%
        \pgfmathrotatepointaround{%
            \pgfpointadd{%
                \beforetop%
                \pgf@y0pt\relax%
                \advance\pgf@x\xradius\relax%
            }{\centerpoint}}{\centerpoint}{\rotate}%
    }
    \anchor{after top}{%
        \getflatcirclepoints%
        \pgfmathrotatepointaround{\pgfpointadd{\beforetopanchor\pgf@y-\pgf@y}{\centerpoint}}{\centerpoint}{\rotate}%
    }
    \anchor{before bottom}{%
        \getflatcirclepoints%
        \pgfmathrotatepointaround{\pgfpointadd{\afterbottomanchor\pgf@y-\pgf@y}{\centerpoint}}{\centerpoint}{\rotate}%
    }
    \anchor{bottom}{%
        \getflatcirclepoints%
        \pgfmathrotatepointaround{%
            \pgfpointadd{%
                \afterbottom%
                \pgf@y0pt\relax%
                \advance\pgf@x-\xradius\relax%
            }{\centerpoint}}{\centerpoint}{\rotate}%
    }
    \anchor{after bottom}{%
        \getflatcirclepoints%
        \pgfmathrotatepointaround{\pgfpointadd{\afterbottomanchor}{\centerpoint}}{\centerpoint}{\rotate}%
    }   
    \backgroundpath{%
        \getflatcirclepoints%
        {%
            \pgf@x\xradius\relax%
            \advance\pgf@x-\outersep\relax%
            \edef\xradius{\the\pgf@x}%
            \pgf@y\yradius\relax%
            \advance\pgf@y-\outersep\relax%
            \edef\yradius{\the\pgf@y}%
            \pgftransformshift{\centerpoint}%
            \pgftransformrotate{\rotate}%
            \pgfpathmoveto{\afterbottom}%
            \pgfpatharc{90}{270}{\xradius and \yradius}%
            \pgfpathlineto{\beforetop\pgf@y-\pgf@y}%
            \pgfpatharc{-90}{90}{\xradius and \yradius}%
            \pgfpathclose%
%           \pgfpathmoveto{\beforetop}%
%           \pgfpatharc{90}{270}{\xradius and \yradius}%
        }%
    }%
    \behindbackgroundpath{%
        \ifpgfflatcircleusescustomfill%
            \getflatcirclepoints%
            \pgf@x\xradius\relax%
            \advance\pgf@x-\outersep\relax%
            \edef\xradius{\the\pgf@x}%
            \pgf@y\yradius\relax%
            \advance\pgf@y-\outersep\relax%
            \edef\yradius{\the\pgf@y}%
            {%              
                \pgftransformshift{\centerpoint}%
                \pgftransformrotate{\rotate}%
                \pgfpathmoveto{\afterbottom}%
                \pgfpatharc{90}{270}{\xradius and \yradius}%
                \pgfpathlineto{\beforetop\pgf@y-\pgf@y}%
                \pgfpatharc{270}{90}{\xradius and \yradius}%
                \pgfpathclose%
                \expandafter\pgfsetfillcolor\expandafter{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/flatcircle body fill}}%
                \pgfusepath{fill}%
                %
                \pgfpathmoveto{\beforetop}%
                \pgfpatharc{90}{-270}{\xradius and \yradius}%
                \pgfpathclose
                \expandafter\pgfsetfillcolor\expandafter{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/flatcircle end fill}}%
                \pgfusepath{fill}%
            }%      
        \fi%    
    }%
    \anchorborder{%
        \pgfextract@process\externalpoint{}%
        \getflatcirclepoints%
        \pgfutil@ifundefined{pgf@flatcircle@referencepoint}{\let\referencepoint\centerpoint}{%
            \let\referencepoint\pgf@flatcircle@referencepoint}%
        \pgfextract@process\externalpoint{%
            \externalpoint%
            \pgf@xa\pgf@x%
            \pgf@ya\pgf@y%
            \referencepoint%
            \advance\pgf@x\pgf@xa%
            \advance\pgf@y\pgf@ya%
        }%
        \pgfmathanglebetweenpoints{\centerpoint}{\externalpoint}%
        \pgfmathsubtract@{\pgfmathresult}{\rotate}%
        \ifdim\pgfmathresult pt<0pt\relax%
            \pgfmathadd@{\pgfmathresult}{360}%
        \fi%
        \let\externalangle\pgfmathresult%
        %
        \pgfmathanglebetweenpoints{\referencepoint}{\pgfpointadd{\afterbottomanchor}{\centerpoint}}%
        \ifdim\externalangle pt<\pgfmathresult pt\relax%
            \pgfmathanglebetweenpoints{\referencepoint}{\pgfpointadd{\beforetopanchor}{\centerpoint}}%
            \ifdim\externalangle pt<\pgfmathresult pt\relax%
                \pgfmathrotatepointaround{%
                    \pgfmathpointintersectionoflineandarc%
                        {\pgfmathrotatepointaround{\externalpoint}{\centerpoint}{-\rotate}}%
                        {\pgfmathrotatepointaround{\referencepoint}{\centerpoint}{-\rotate}}%
                        {%
                            \beforetop%
                            \pgf@xa\pgf@x%
                            \centerpoint%
                            \advance\pgf@x\pgf@xa%
                        }%
                        {0}{90}{\xradius and \yradius}%
                    }{\centerpoint}{\rotate}%
            \else%
                \pgfpointintersectionoflines{%
                    \pgfmathrotatepointaround{\pgfpointadd{\afterbottomanchor}{\centerpoint}}%
                        {\centerpoint}{\rotate}}{%
                    \pgfmathrotatepointaround{\pgfpointadd{\beforetopanchor}{\centerpoint}}%
                        {\centerpoint}{\rotate}}%
                    {\referencepoint}{\externalpoint}%
            \fi%
        \else%
            \pgfmathanglebetweenpoints{\referencepoint}{\pgfpointadd{\afterbottomanchor\pgf@y-\pgf@y}{\centerpoint}}%
            \ifdim\externalangle pt>\pgfmathresult pt\relax%
                \pgfmathanglebetweenpoints{\referencepoint}{\pgfpointadd{\beforetopanchor\pgf@y-\pgf@y}{\centerpoint}}%
                \ifdim\externalangle pt>\pgfmathresult pt\relax%
                    \pgfmathrotatepointaround{%
                        \pgfmathpointintersectionoflineandarc%
                            {\pgfmathrotatepointaround{\externalpoint}{\centerpoint}{-\rotate}}%
                            {\pgfmathrotatepointaround{\referencepoint}{\centerpoint}{-\rotate}}%
                            {%
                                \beforetop%
                                \pgf@xa\pgf@x%
                                \centerpoint
                                \advance\pgf@x\pgf@xa%
                            }%
                            {270}{360}{\xradius and \yradius}%
                        }{\centerpoint}{\rotate}%
                \else%
                    \pgfpointintersectionoflines{%
                        \pgfmathrotatepointaround{\pgfpointadd{\afterbottomanchor\pgf@y-\pgf@y}{\centerpoint}}%
                            {\centerpoint}{\rotate}}{%
                        \pgfmathrotatepointaround{\pgfpointadd{\beforetopanchor\pgf@y-\pgf@y}{\centerpoint}}%
                            {\centerpoint}{\rotate}}%
                        {\referencepoint}{\externalpoint}%
                \fi%
            \else%
                \pgfmathrotatepointaround{%
                    \pgfmathpointintersectionoflineandarc%
                        {\pgfmathrotatepointaround{\externalpoint}{\centerpoint}{-\rotate}}%
                        {\pgfmathrotatepointaround{\referencepoint}{\centerpoint}{-\rotate}}%
                        {%
                            \afterbottom%
                            \pgf@xa\pgf@x%
                            \centerpoint
                            \advance\pgf@x\pgf@xa%
                        }%
                        {90}{270}{\xradius and \yradius}%
                    }{\centerpoint}{\rotate}%
            \fi%
        \fi%
    }
}
\makeatother

\newcommand*\comp[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{
\node[flatcircle,draw,inner ysep=1pt,inner xsep=0pt] (char) {#1};}}

\begin{document}
\comp{x} \comp{\( x+y+z \)} \comp{y} \comp{\( \int \)}

\end{document}
```

[image: Flatcircle sample]

This is just the code from `pgflibraryshapes.geometric.code.tex` for the cylinder shape,  with a few lines commented out.  I have replaced `cylinder` by `flatcircle` throughout, commented out the lines that draw the leftward point half circle on the right of the cylinder, and in `\pgfextract@process\beforetop` commented out the shifting commands that moved the rightside of the cylinder to the right, and flipped the sign of a correction to `\pgf@x` by `\pgf@xb`.  Finally, in calling this code setting the inner separations separately in the x and y directions, results in a round circle in the first case.  The code is long, because it includes all the pgf material to set anchors, allow rotations etc.

Answer (score 2):

For a first approximation see the code below

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newlength{\tempA}
\newlength{\tempB}

\newcommand{\comp}[1]{%
  \settowidth{\tempA}{M}%
  \settowidth{\tempB}{\ensuremath{#1}}%
  \ifdimcomp{\tempA}{<}{\tempB}{\inlozenge{#1}}{\incircle{#1}}%
  }

\newcommand{\incircle}[1]{\tikz[baseline]\draw[anchor=base] (0,0) node[draw,circle]{\ensuremath{#1}};}
\newcommand{\inlozenge}[1]{\tikz[baseline]\draw[anchor=base] (0,0) node[draw,rounded corners]{\ensuremath{#1}};}

\begin{document}
$\comp{m}_{\comp{x+x}}+\comp{A=B}$

\end{document}
```