# Is there a symbol for a circled intersection? Like \oplus for the plus sign

Tags: symbols, math-operators

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I put a circle around an operator?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53698/how-do-i-put-a-circle-around-an-operator)

Is there a symbol for a circled intersection sign? or an alternative way to render something like in the image below? Something like `\oplus` for the plus sign. I need to use this symbol inside a math environment as a sub index.

The result I am expecting is something like this: [image]

But with this symbol [image] instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ther is certainly a duplicate/related of this question which I can't find right now. For the time being I am posting this tikz solution.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
%% Code borrowed from Altermundus http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53698/
\newcommand{\myointersection}{
  \mathbin{
    \mathchoice
      {\ointersection{\displaystyle}}
      {\ointersection{\textstyle}}
      {\ointersection{\scriptstyle}}
      {\ointersection{\scriptscriptstyle}}
  }
}
\newcommand{\ointersection}[1]{\tikz[baseline=(X.base), inner sep=0, outer sep=0]\node[draw,circle] (X) {$#1\cap$};}

\begin{document}
\[m^{\Omega}_{i\myointersection j}\left(H\right)\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Sadly, it doesn't render very pretty when used as a subindex... it is to big.

Comment: @FelipeAguirre: This is not designed for a sub index. The duplicate I mentioned, (If you can find it) can be used for such things.

Comment: Can you please give me some clues or keywords to search for the other question?

Comment: @FelipeAguirre: See this [How do I put a circle around an operator?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/53698)

Comment: Using TikZ to create math operators might lead to inconvenient processing times when the document gets longer. In addition, you should adapt line thickness to math style to better match the operator strokes.