# Circled equal with same size as \oplus/\otimes with pdflatex

Tags: symbols, math-operators, circles

## My question

I am trying to make an equal circled of the same size as `\oplus` or `\otimes`, etc.
I tried to use the solution provided here :

> [How do I put a circle around an operator?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53698/how-do-i-put-a-circle-around-an-operator)

However, the size of the operators are  not the same.

I used as preamble :

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand\incircbin
{%
  \mathpalette\@incircbin
}
\newcommand\@incircbin[2]
{%
  \mathbin%
  {%
    \ooalign{\hidewidth$#1#2$\hidewidth\crcr$#1\bigcirc$}%
  }%
}
\newcommand{\oeq}{\incircbin{=}}
\makeatother
```

And, inside the document itself :

```
  $\oeq$, $\oplus$, $\otimes$
```

Which is displayed as follow :

[image]

As you can notice, the operator `\oeq` is bigger than the others. Is there a way to get the exact size used by `$\oplus$` or `$\otimes$` ? Please note that I would rather keep the compilation with `pdflatex`.

Thank you in advance for any help you may provide.

---

## Minimal working example

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\incircbin
{%
  \mathpalette\@incircbin
}
\newcommand\@incircbin[2]
{%
  \mathbin%
  {%
    \ooalign{\hidewidth$#1#2$\hidewidth\crcr$#1\bigcirc$}%
  }%
}
\newcommand{\oeq}{\incircbin{=}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\Huge   $\oeq$, $\oplus$, $\otimes$
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is a really nicely-asked question :) presumably you need to resize the circle - perhaps you could use resizebox from the graphics package?

Comment: @cmhughes maybe possible but I think it will be difficult to obtain the same line thickness then. Maybe its easier to [measure the hight](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2939541) of the original symbol and redo them all in TikZ.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi sounds like a plan :)

Comment: @cmhughes : Thank you your remark and for your proposal as well. However, the solution proposed below by LaRiFaRi fits well with what I expected. Have you both a nice day =)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

One solution would be to use the unicode-symbol [U+229C](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/229c/index.htm) for this. For example with the package `unicode-math`.

```
% arara: lualatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\begin{document}
\[\oplus\ominus\otimes\oslash\odot\circledcirc\circledast\circledequal\circleddash\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

`\circledequal` or `\symbol{"229C}` yield your desired symbol in the right size for the most common fonts.

**Edit**:

As mentioned in comment, the OP wants to stick to PDFLaTeX. For this case, I would choose the binary operators defined in the package `mathabx` which look even nicer than the default ones (in my eyes). The macro `\ovoid` yields an empty circle of the size of the other operators.

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{mathabx}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\incircbin
{%
  \mathpalette\@incircbin
}
\newcommand\@incircbin[2]
{%
  \mathbin%
  {%
    \ooalign{\hidewidth$#1#2$\hidewidth\crcr$#1\ovoid$}%
  }%
}
\newcommand{\oeq}{\incircbin{=}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\Huge   $\oeq$, $\oplus$, $\otimes$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there an equivalent solution with `pdflatex` please ? I am actually receiving this error : `! Fatal fontspec error: "cannot-use-pdftex" ! The fontspec package requires either XeTeX or LuaTeX to function.`, and I wish I could stay under `pdflatex` compilation process.

Comment: @booba24 Please see my update for a PDFLaTeX-version.

Comment: Your second proposals suits me perfectly, thank you very much for your prompt help !

Comment: @booba24 You are very welcome. Btw: found it here: http://www.tex.ac.uk/tex-archive/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf

Comment: Thank you for the link, that may be useful in the future ! Have a nice day ! =)