# Is there a way to make the command "\odiv"?

Tags: symbols

It is well known that `$\oplus$` produces a plus sign with a circle around it, similarly `$\otimes$` does the and same with the `$\times$` symbol, etc.

I was wondering if there a way to make a command which would do the same for `$\div$` ?

The command isn't available by default, to my knowledge, and I'm not experienced enough with defining such commands myself.

Comment: This question seems more of a duplicate of [How do I put a circle around an operator?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53698/how-do-i-put-a-circle-around-an-operator) than the decision. Replace every `\land` you find there by `\div` and you get what you wanted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want the `mathabx` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathabx}
\begin{document}
$x \odiv y$
\end{document}
```

[image]

In general, you want to look in [*The Comprehensive LaTeX Symbol List*](http://tug.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf).

As egreg pointed out, `mathabx` changes the other math symbols. You can get just `\odiv` by declaring the `matha` font and defining the symbol. Instead of `\usepackage{mathabx}`, you can use this. Note that it won't exactly match the normal LaTeX math symbols like `\otimes`.

```
\DeclareFontFamily{U}{matha}{\hyphenchar\font45}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{matha}{m}{n}{
      <5> <6> <7> <8> <9> <10> gen * matha
      <10.95> matha10 <12> <14.4> <17.28> <20.74> <24.88> matha12
      }{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{matha}{U}{matha}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\odiv}         {2}{matha}{"63}
```

Comment: Usual *caveat*: the package changes *all* math symbols. See also [Importing a single symbol from a different font](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14386)