# how to define semantic logic "implies" and "not" operators for use in LyX

Tags: symbols, lyx, math-operators, logic, stacking-symbols

In Schechter's *Classical and nonclassical logics*, he distinguishes symbols at the semantic level, from those at the syntactic level, by encircling the operators. For example, formal logic uses "∧" (`\wedge`) for conjunction, while semantic logic uses an encircled version, which can be implemented by `\owedge` from [the `stmaryrd` package](https://ctan.org/pkg/stmaryrd):

[image: owedge symbol]

But semantic operators corresponding to implication ("→", `\rightarrow`) and negation ("¬", `\neg`) don't exist among [the usual symbols](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf). How can these be generated in such a way that they can be used from LyX?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, I keep all of my math macros in a separate LyX file that I can then include from other LyX documents (via Insert > File > Child Document). The solution requires placing some of the LaTeX code in a LyX preamble (because LyX macros can't handle the `\mathpalette` macro's structure). So I also have a separate LaTeX file for the preamble code, which I can then `\input{…}` in the "LaTeX preamble" setting of both the child and parent LyX documents.

In `math-macros-preamble.tex`, I place:

```latex
\newcommand{\semanticlogic}[2]{\ooalign{$\m@th#1\ocircle$\cr\scalebox{0.9}[1]{$\m@th#1#2$}\cr}}

\newcommand{\encircled}[1]{\mathpalette\semanticlogic{#1}}
```

`\semanticlogic` is a macro that takes as its arguments (1) the style macro (provided by `\mathpalette`) and (2) the operator to be encircled. The `\encircled` macro wraps `\mathpalette` so that it's easy to use inside a LyX macro.

In `math-macros.lyx`, I add `\input{math-macros-preamble}` to its preamble, then define a macro from `\newcommand{\oimplies}{\mathbin{\encircled{\shortrightarrow}}}`, giving it a LyX representation like `\mathbin{$\ocircle\shortrightarrow$}` so that it looks nicer when inlined into the parent document. Similarly, I create `\onot` as `\encircled{\mkern1mu \neg}`.

In the parent document, where I use the logic operators, I also add `\input{math-macros-preamble}` to its preamble, and include `math-macros.lyx` as a child document.

[image: example semantic relation with operators]

Comment: A related answer—https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53698/how-do-i-put-a-circle-around-an-operator—covers the case where the encircled operator should be centered. Here the operators are left-aligned, as in Schechter's book. It's a matter of taste, certainly.

Answer (score 1):

The circle is a bit thicker, but I believe the emulation is passable.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,stmaryrd,graphicx}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\orightarrow}{\mathrel{\mathpalette\math@circled\rightarrow}}
\newcommand{\oleftarrow}{\mathrel{\mathpalette\math@circled\leftarrow}}
\newcommand{\olnot}{\mathord{\mathpalette\math@circled\lnot}}

\newcommand{\math@circled}[2]{%
  \begingroup
  \sbox0{$\m@th#1\owedge$}%
  \sbox2{$\m@th#1\mskip1mu$}%
  \raisebox{\wd2}{%
    \resizebox{\wd\z@}{!}{%
      \ooalign{$\m@th#1\varbigcirc$\cr\hidewidth$\m@th#1#2$\hidewidth\cr}%
    }%
  }%
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$X\orightarrow Y\owedge \olnot Z\oleftarrow U$

{\ooalign{$\orightarrow$\cr$\owedge$\cr}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The second line is to show that the symbol have the same dimensions.

Whether you're able to use this with LyX, I don't know.

Comment: `\mathord` is new to me. Is it really necessary?

Comment: @Mike Not really necessary, but logically better to have it