# An alternative to the symbol \modtwosum of stix package

Tags: symbols, mtpro, amssymb, stix, stackengine

This is a trivial question. We know that in the table 72: *Variable-sized Math Operators* to the pag. 40, we have the symbol for the line integral of a closed path named `\oint` for the circuiting.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\begin{document}
Table 72: Variable-sized Math Operators pag. 40.
\[\oint\]
\end{document}
```

But the high school students are not familiar with this symbol and I have thought of to use the symbol of the sum with the circle inside. But this symbol is only declared in `stix` fonts (see to pag. 46 `\modtwosum`).

[image]

If I should use `mtpro2[lite]` (that use the font Times New Roman) or the classic `amssymb` I should overlapping the two symbols of summation and the small circle in the center or can I find a more effective or best strategy?

Any kind of suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: You might try doing that with  `\stackinset` command from the `stackengine` package.

Comment: @Bernard Very kind Bernard, I was putting it in the tags :-)) thank you very much for the suggestion.

Comment: This being said, do you really think a high-school student in not able to understand the `\oint`  symbol, if it is explained?

Comment: @Bernard There is a real reason. When using approximations for integrals we use the summation symbol. In high school Physics books the symbol for circuiting is used with `\oint`. In order to avoid sterile controversy with those who are not proficient prof. in math and physics and think they are, especially in my school, instead to use `$C_{\gamma}(\mathbf{E})$` I would like to use the summation symbol with the circle. I'm just telling you that most students don't even know how to use a calculator, and I'm really unhappy about this.

Comment: I see. Note that, when I was a high schooler, calculators did not exist, but was taught (at 11!) how to calculate a square root by hand, with a method similar to long division – just a bit more complex.

Comment: @Bernard So I'm getting older in age too. I have a book where there is a method to calculate square roots by hand by dividing the number into groups of two with a point. I never used it when I was 11 because it wasn't in the math textbooks, but I discovered it around 25, 26 years of age. I've forgotten how to do it by now and should review the mechanism.

Comment: It's just a tricky use of the formula $(a+b)^2=\dots$. Later I discovered that the mathematical justification was given as a problem for a competitive exam for an engineer school…

Comment: @Bernard I do not know the trick but I could ask a question on MSE community :-)

Comment: It's easier to explain from an example  on a black board. Roughly, the expansion of $(a+b)^2$ is written as $a^2 + (2a+b)\cdot b$.

Comment: If you can use `unicode-math`, several fonts have it, including XITS, STIX Two and New Computer Modern.

Comment: @Davislor Hi kindest. I not like much the `unicode-math`. I like innovations, but on some things I am a traditionalist. :-)

Comment: @Sebastiano You can have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/46389/4427

Comment: @egreg Kindest Enrico. No otherwise I wouldn't have asked the question. My question, in all sincerity, is therefore a duplicate and should be closed. I thank you for the information. My besttttt regards.

Answer (score 2):

You could also borrow the symbol from STIX without loading the whole font.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\makeatletter
\DeclareFontEncoding{LS2}{}{\noaccents@}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{LS2}{stix}{m}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFont{largesymbols}  {LS2}{stixex}   {m} {n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\modtwosumop}            {\mathop}{largesymbols}{"C4}
\def\modtwosum{\DOTSI\modtwosumop\slimits@}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\( \displaystyle \modtwosum_{i=1}^n a_i \)
\( \modtwosum_{i=1}^n a_i \)
\( \scriptstyle \modtwosum_{i=1}^n a_i \)
\( \scriptscriptstyle \modtwosum_{i=1}^n a_i \)
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: In my humble opinion the two responses are equivalent. So to be fair I will not put a green check mark as I have done on other occasions but will thank otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

The following defines an `\osum` that is just an overlayed `\circ` and `\sum` with some manually applied spacing.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*\osum
  {%
    \mathop
      {%
        \mathchoice
          {%
            \rlap
              {%
                $\displaystyle
                \mkern9mu
                \raisebox{-.1\height}{\scalebox{1.2}{$\displaystyle\circ$}}$%
              }%
          }%
          {\rlap{$\textstyle\mkern6.3mu\circ$}}%
          {\rlap{$\scriptstyle\mkern6.5mu\circ$}}%
          {\rlap{$\scriptscriptstyle\mkern5.5mu\circ$}}%
        \sum
      }%
    \slimits@
  }
\makeatother

\begin{document}
Table 72: Variable-sized Math Operators pag. 40.
\[\oint\]
\[\osum\]
${\displaystyle\osum}\osum_{\osum_{\osum}}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, see the post to the @Vincent. Always thank you very much.