# \newcommand: How to determine if in math mode (and then include $ $)?

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros

I would like to define a new command which should determine (within a tikz plot)
whether its argument is in math mode or not. If so, it should wrap the argument
with $ $. I found \ifmode to do this, but it's not working. Here is my minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[american,ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand*{\yellowemph}[1]{%
  \tikz[baseline=(text.base)]\node(text)[rectangle, fill=yellow, rounded
corners, inner sep=0.3mm]{\ifmmode $#1$\else #1\fi};%
}

\begin{document}
\yellowemph{word}% works
\yellowemph{$\frac{1}{2}$}% works
$\yellowemph{\frac{1}{2}}$% does not work
\end{document}
```

I am aware of `\ensuremath`, however, this *always* switches to math mode. I would like to keep text as is if not in math mode (see `\yellowemph{word}` for example).

**SOLUTION**

As posted below, this is a solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[american,ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newif\ifstartedinmathmode
\newcommand*{\yellowemph}[1]{%
  \relax\ifmmode\startedinmathmodetrue\else\startedinmathmodefalse\fi
  \tikz[baseline=(text.base)]\node(text)[rectangle, fill=yellow, rounded
corners, inner sep=0.3mm]
  {\ifstartedinmathmode$#1$\else#1\fi};%
}

\begin{document}
\yellowemph{word}
$\int_0^\infty f(\yellowemph{x})\,dx$
\yellowemph{$\displaystyle\frac{1}{2}$}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You could use `\ensuremath{}`

Comment: Do you know about the `\ensuremath` command ?

Comment: There's always `\ensuremath` :D

Comment: But `\ensuremath` *always* uses math mode right? that's not what I want for text such as in the first line, for example.

Comment: Incidentally, there's not just one mathmode.  See http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1223/86 for where I wanted a similar functionality.

Comment: @MariusHofert: Sorry, I just got carried away and went with the crowd. Weirdly I [asked](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46376/writing-specific-versions-of-an-operator-for-display-and-inline-modes) and [answered](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46356/the-modulo-two-sum-sign-in-latex) questions involving `mathchoice` yesterday, which is kind of related.

Comment: If you want to leave math mode only if you are in math mode, without moving otherwise, you can just use \mbox{not in math mode}.  This writes "not in math mode" not in math mode, independently of the surrounding mode.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The argument to a `\node` command is *always* processed in text mode, independently of whether the `tikzpicture` has been started in text or in math mode. So the best way out is to put the `$` symbols in the argument.

```
\newcommand*{\yellowemph}[1]{%
  \tikz[baseline=(text.base)]\node(text)[rectangle, fill=yellow, rounded
corners, inner sep=0.3mm]{#1};%
}

\begin{document}
\yellowemph{word}
\yellowemph{$\frac{1}{2}$}
```

You might try a more complicated approach with a conditional:

```
\newif\ifstartedinmathmode
\newcommand*{\yellowemph}[1]{%
  \relax\ifmmode\startedinmathmodetrue\else\startedinmathmodefalse\fi
  \tikz[baseline=(text.base)]\node(text)[rectangle, fill=yellow, rounded
corners, inner sep=0.3mm]
  {\ifstartedinmathmode$#1$\else#1\fi};%
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I am aware of this. I was just wondering if it is possible to let LaTeX include the `$ $` if necessary (so if the argument `#1` is something in math mode)

Comment: @MariusHofert That's what the second of egreg's solutions does (I was about to post exactly the same code ..., only I forgot the `\relax` at the start).  Incidentally, I've given you a solution to the highlighter question which avoids this problem.

Comment: @egreg This will of course will still give an error if you use `\frac` in text leaving us with the first simpler solution;)

Answer (score 10):

You need to use `\ensuremath` or fix the error in your conditional:

```
\relax\ifmmode#1\else $#1$\fi
```

Comment: You might want to put a `\relax` before `\ifmmode` to ensure that it isn't expanded prematurely in some cases, like at the beginning of a tabular cell.

Comment: Thanks for helping, Yiannis. This does not work as expected. I want `$ $` *if* I am in math mode, and just the argument otherwise. Your solution does it the other way around. The problem is that if I put the `$ $` in the first part of the conditional, it does not work anymore. Also note that `\ensuremath` *always* switches to math mode, however, I would like to not do this for words (see the first line of my example after `\begin{document}`.

Comment: @MariusHofert Hm.. I see problem is you want to have more than two conditions. If you are sending text and you are in mathmode, you need to include it in a `\text{#1}, problem will fail if you do send a `\frac`. Not too sure if it is feasible. Suggest define two commands `\hltext` and `\hlmath`.

Comment: @MartinScharrer --Thanks. Normally I would do this type of macro in a `\DeclareRobustCommand` omitting the relax. But your sugestion is good.

Comment: @Marius: what you describe does not make sense; you are trying to get into math mode when you are in math mode (`if in math mode`, `start math mode`. See what I mean?), which ends up trying to start a display math mode as a result. (`$$`)

Comment: @morbusg It's more like "if in math mode, make a note of that, now do something that forces us out of math mode if we were in it, but using the fact that we noted it, start math mode again".

Comment: @AndrewStacey: I can see that from egreg's answer. I was commenting on Marius' comment on this here Yiannis' answer. I wanted to emphasize that `$` means: `start math mode`.

Comment: @morbusg Ah, I see.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
\newcommand*{\textyellowemph}[1]{\tikz[baseline=(text.base)]\node(text)[rectangle, fill=yellow, rounded, inner sep=0.3mm]{#1};}
\newcommand*{\mathyellowemph}[1]{\tikz[baseline=(text.base)]\node(text)[rectangle, fill=yellow, rounded, inner sep=0.3mm]{\ensuremath{#1}};}
\newcommand*{\yellowemph}[1]{\ifmmode\mathyellowemph{#1}\else\textyellowemph{#1}\fi}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.