# Spacing is off with convenience command

Tags: spacing, conditionals, letterspacing

I want to define a command called `\ksp{}` that looks like this:

```
\newcommand*{\ksp}{K_{sp}}
```

However, this function gives an error if it's not invoked in math mode. See example here.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand*{\ksp}{K_{sp}}
\begin{document}
  Determine the \ksp{} of xyz. This will give an error 
\end{document}
```

So, I modified the command to be inline math mode.

```
\newcommand*{\ksp}{$K_{sp}$}
```

However, this new version of the command gives an error if I invoke the function while **already** in math mode. See example here.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand*{\ksp}{$K_{sp}$}
\begin{document}
    \begin{equation}
  Determine the \ksp{} of xyz. will get an error.
    \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

So, I made a newer version that tries to determine if we're already in math mode or not when the command is invoked. I pilfered this code from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46492/newcommand-how-to-determine-if-in-math-mode-and-then-include)

```
% Ksp
\newif\ifstartedinmathmode
\newcommand*{\ksp}{
    \relax\ifmmode\startedinmathmodetrue\else\startedinmathmodefalse\fi
    {\ifstartedinmathmode K_{sp}\else\hspace{0pt}$K_{sp}$\fi}
    }
```

This command (above) works under both conditions. However, it introduces an extra "space" in front of (and maybe after) the **Ksp**. You can see this in the document below.

```
\documentclass{article}
% Ksp
\newif\ifstartedinmathmode
\newcommand*{\ksp}{
    \relax\ifmmode\startedinmathmodetrue\else\startedinmathmodefalse\fi
    {\ifstartedinmathmode K_{sp}\else$K_{sp}$\fi}
}
\begin{document}
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item Determine the $K_{sp}$ of blahblah. \% this is the normal way of writing the term.
        \item Determine the \ksp{} of blahblah. \% this is with the conditional command and it has extra whitespace surrounding the term.    
    \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Questions:

- any way to fix the spacing issue?
- should I be taking a completely different approach? I am simply trying to avoid typing some complicated formatting over and over again (Ksp is a simplification of the formatting that I'm actually trying to do, but it illustrates the point well enough).

Comment: With the first definition, use `Determine the $\ksp$ of xyz.` It's as easy as that.

Comment: you have added two spaces to your definition after the `{` and `}`  but simpler is use `\ensuremath{K_{sp}}` but better really is just use `K_{sp}` and mark up math explicitly as for all standard latex math commands like `\alpha` or `\sum`.

Comment: Very nicely written question. I liked how you went through the various permutations that brought you here. I answered assuming you want to leave an explicit space before and after your `\ksp{}` in text mode for code readability purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer.  I put a negative \hskip on each side of your math.

```
    \documentclass{article}
% Ksp
\newif\ifstartedinmathmode
\newcommand*{\ksp}{
\relax\ifmmode\startedinmathmodetrue\else\startedinmathmodefalse\fi
{\ifstartedinmathmode K_{sp}\else\hskip-1mm$K_{sp}$\hskip-1mm\fi}
}
\begin{document}
    \begin{enumerate}
    \item Determine the $K_{sp}$ of blahblah. \% this is the normal way of writing the term.
    \item Determine the \ksp{} of blahblah. \% this is with the conditional command and it has extra whitespace surrounding the term.    
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Produces:
[image]

However, a better answer, as shown in the comment by @David Carlisle would be:

```
\documentclass{article}
% Ksp

\newcommand*{\ksp}{\ensuremath$K_{sp}$}

\begin{document}
 \begin{enumerate}
  \item Determine the $K_{sp}$ of blahblah. \% this is the normal way of writing the term.
  \item Determine the \ksp{} of blahblah. \% this is with the conditional command and it has extra whitespace surrounding the term.    
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Produces:
[image]

Comment: thank you for the comments. I'm new to this and was unaware of \ensuremath. Looked at your profile. LaTeX is beautiful.

Comment: I wasn't aware of it either until today.